# Are uninitialized struct members always set to zero?

Tags: c, struct

Consider a C struct:

```c
struct T {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

When this is partially initialized as in

```c
struct T t = {42};
```

is `t.y` guaranteed to be 0 or is this an implementation decision of the compiler?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

item 8.5.1.7 of standard draft:

> -7- If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the
>   aggregate, then each member not
>   explicitly initialized shall be
>   default-initialized (dcl.init).
>   [Example:
>
> ```
> struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
> S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes ss.a with 1, ss.b with
>   "asdf", and ss.c with the value of an
>   expression of the form int(), that is,
>   0. ]

Answer (score 51):

It's guaranteed to be 0 if it's partially initialized, just like array initializers. If it's uninitialized, it'll be unknown.

```
struct T t; // t.x, t.y will NOT be initialized to 0 (not guaranteed to)

struct T t = {42}; // t.y will be initialized to 0.
```

Similarly:

```
int x[10]; // Won't be initialized.

int x[10] = {1}; // initialized to {1,0,0,...}
```

Sample:

```
// a.c
struct T { int x, y };
extern void f(void*);
void partialInitialization() {
  struct T t = {42};
  f(&t);
}
void noInitialization() {
  struct T t;
  f(&t);
}

// Compile with: gcc -O2 -S a.c

// a.s:

; ...
partialInitialzation:
; ...
; movl $0, -4(%ebp)     ;;;; initializes t.y to 0.
; movl $42, -8(%ebp)
; ...
noInitialization:
; ... ; Nothing related to initialization. It just allocates memory on stack.
```

Comment: Great answer with the compiler example output. I it's really hard to decide whether to accept this one or bb's answer which quotes the relevant part of the spec. I wish I could accept both.

Comment: Note that if the variable is global, it is guaranteed to be initialized to zero on Unix even without initializer. It is a Unix guarantee that unfortunately is not found on Windows.

Comment: (OT) that GCC's assembly language is really ugly.

Comment: Agreed. I hate AT&T syntax. Viva la Intel Syntax!

Comment: @Juliano: That information is completely incorrect. Global variables (and all variables with static storage duration) which are not explicitly initialized are always initially zero. This is a fundamental part of the C language and has nothing to do with your OS.

Comment: I found a bug related to this issue. This answer has finally given me the reason to empty initialize a simple struct. I previously thought leaving it as non-initialized had the same behavior. Maybe I got confused because of the global variables as you mention.

Answer (score 2):

No. it is guaranteed to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answers above, I also found out that (at least with GCC) you can "partly initialize" a struct without explicitly assigning any member by using `{}`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    struct a a = {};

    printf ("{.x=%d, .y=%d}\n", a.x, a.y);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out: `{.x=0, .y=0}`.